# Simulate 4 finger long press on iOS simulator

Tags: ios-simulator, gestures

I know that there are ways of simulating two finger taps, but is there a way of doing it for 4 fingers long press. I'm trying to test something in automation and I want to be able to simulate this on the iOS simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of. I think the iPhone Simulator included in the SDK is the only one that exists. You can't test a 3-fingered gesture without using the actual device.